# How to detect if Storyboards build for IBDesignable in Xcode Run Script

Tags: ios, xcode

In `Build Phases` for targets, we can add `Run Script Phases` and they will be executed every time we build.
Then is there a way to detect if the build is initiated from storyboards or not?
Because the storyboards (or xib files) also initiate the build when they contain custom classes inside which use `IBDesignable`.

My goal is that executing a run script only when I manually build the code by pressing `[Command]` + `[B]`.

I looked for [Build settings reference](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6) document, but I couldn't find the way for this.

Any help would be appreciated.